# What is the intuition behind this (concrete) system of equations? (It has to do with orthogonal projections onto non-orthogonal subspaces)

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices

I've been told in my geometry lectures (at university) that a way of calculating the projection of a vector onto a subspace is solving a linear system of equations. The only thing I don't know is what is the **intuition** behind such system. An answer giving a geometrical approach would work for me too!

(Maybe the text down below is a bit long but it's because the question needs a bit of background, I think).

Before that, let $E = [u_1, ..., u_n]$ be a vector space and $F = [v_1, ..., v_r]$ a subspace of $E$. Now, we know we can create the matrix $G$ (sometimes called $M$) in which the element ($g_{ij}$) is the dot product of $v_i$ and $v_j$. (Dot products will be denoted by $<v_i, v_j>$). That means:

$$
G = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    <v_1, v_1> & <v_1, v_2> & \cdots & <v_1, v_r> \\
    <v_2, v_1> & <v_2, v_2> & \cdots & <v_2, v_r> \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    <v_r, v_1> & <v_r, v_2> & \cdots & <v_r, v_r> \\
   \end{pmatrix} \\
$$

(Note: 1. Because of dot product properties, this matrix is symmetrical. 2. Since all vectors in $F$ are linearly independent, it has an inverse. 3. If the vectors of $F$ are orthogonal the matrix is diagonal. 4. If the vectors of $F$ are orthonomal, de matrix $G$ is simply the Identity matrix. 5. It's called $G$ because it is Gram's matrix, or $M$ because it is called "Metric matrix" too).

Having said that, this matrix is the one that appears in the system of equations that is used to find the projection I was talking about:

Suppose $w \in E$ and $w \not\in F$. We want to know the projection of $w$ onto $F$, that is $\Pi_F (w)$. I know a way to think of it is by using "least squares" (by thinking $G = S^tS$, where $S$ is the matrix that contains the vectors $v_1, ..., v_r$ in its columns), but that's not really how I want to understand it.

I know that the vector space $E$ can be decomposed as $E = F \bigoplus F^\perp$ and I also know that we want to find the linear combination of the vectors of $F$ ($\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_r $) and $F^\perp$ ($\alpha_{r+1}, ..., \alpha_n$) such that $w = \alpha_1 v_1 + \cdots + \alpha_r v_r + \alpha_{r+1} v_{r+1}+ \cdots + \alpha_n v_n$ and just take the first $r$ coordinates, because that will be precisely the projection of $w$ onto $F$. Putting all this together, we see:

$$w = \alpha_1v_1 + \cdots + \alpha_rv_r \space + \space "vector"$$
where "vector" $\in F^\perp$. The next step after getting to this point sounds like "magic" to me: **take the dot product of the equation with $v_1$, ..., and the dot product of the equation with $v_r$**. Doing this leads us (finally) to the following system of equations:

$ \begin{pmatrix}
    <v_1, v_1> & <v_1, v_2> & \cdots & <v_1, v_r> \\
    <v_2, v_1> & <v_2, v_2> & \cdots & <v_2, v_r> \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    <v_r, v_1> & <v_r, v_2> & \cdots & <v_r, v_r> \\
  \end{pmatrix} 
 \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha_1  \\
    \vdots \\
    \vdots  \\
    \alpha_r  \\
  \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
    <v_1, w>  \\
    <v_2, w> \\
    \vdots  \\
    <v_r, w>  \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$

And that's what I don't understand. I get it if the basis (of the subspace $F$) is orthogonal or orthonormal, but what do (geometrically) mean the dot products like $<v_i, v_j>$ with $i \neq j$? I've tried to rewrite the system using $<v_i, v_j> = |v_i||v_j|*cos(\alpha)$ and I've noticed that in the i-th equation, $|v_i|$ cancells out, but I coldn't deduce much more... 
Also, why do you take the dot product? I know it has a lot to do with projections, but I don't know how it... "fits" in here. Is there a way to construct they system of equations more... intuitively?
That's the doubt. I hope you understand my question.

Thanks a lot for reading this far!

Comment: I can't think of anything very deep to say about the matrix equation. It seems like it just expresses the fact that we can package the information contained in the metric in different ways. On the left hand side we think of the metric as a fixed matrix. On the right hand side, I guess you could say that we think of the metric as an isomorphism between the vector space and the dual space.